# How to avoid buffer overflow with C struct array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc, buffer-overflow

I'm running into buffer overflows when reading a file in C and copying character arrays. There are three potentially offending pieces of code and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

The first reads a file and populates it into a hashmap:

```
bool load_file(const char* in_file, hmap hashtable[]) {

    for(int x = 0; x < HASH_SIZE; x++) {
        hashtable[x] = NULL;
    }

    FILE *fptr = fopen(in_file, "r");

    char c[LENGTH] = "";
    c[0] = '\0';

    while (fgets(c, sizeof(c)-1, fptr) != NULL) {

        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        hmap new_node = n;      
        new_node->next = NULL;
        strncpy(new_node->content, c, LENGTH-1);

        // do stuff to put it into the hashtable
    }

    fclose(fptr);
    return true;
}
```

The second checks whether given content is in the hashmap:

```
bool check_content(const char* content, hmap hashtable[]) {

    char c_content[LENGTH] = "";
    strncpy(c_content, content, LENGTH-1);

    // do stuff to check if it's in the hashmap

    return false;
}
```

and the third parses a given file and checks whether its content is in the hashmap:

```
int check_file(FILE* fp, hmap hashtable[], char * not_found[]) {

    int num_not_found = 0;
    char c[1000] = "";

    while (fgets(c, sizeof(c)-1, fp) != NULL) {

        char * pch;
        char curToken[LENGTH] = "";

        pch = strtok (c," ");
        strncpy(curToken, pch, LENGTH-1);
        curToken[LENGTH]=0;

        if(!check_content(curToken, hashtable)) {
            not_found[num_not_found] = malloc(LENGTH*sizeof(not_found[num_not_found]));
            strncpy(not_found[num_not_found], curToken, LENGTH-1);
            num_not_found++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return num_not_found;
}
```

Finally, main calls these and frees mallocs:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    hmap hashtable[HASH_SIZE];
    load_file(argv[2], hashtable);

    FILE *fptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char * not_found[MAX_ENTRIES];
    int num_not_found = check_file(fptr, hashtable, not_found);

    for(int x=0; x<num_not_found; x++) {
        free(not_found[x]);
    }

    for(int y=0; hashtable[y] != NULL; y++) {
        free(hashtable[y]);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

My question is this: for each of the three code snippets, what have I done that causes buffer overflows? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `strncpy(curToken, pch, LENGTH-1);` (what is `pch` at this time??)

Comment: oops, sorry about that. pch is what's returned from tokenizing the line. updated the code.

Comment: `sizeof(not_found[num_not_found])` is the same as `sizeof(a_pointer)` not the size of what is pointed to by `not_found[num_not_found]`. (unless you want an allocation of `LENGTH * sizeof (a_pointer)`) It appears it should result in an over-allocation rather than an under-allocation, but without seeing a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it is impossible to be sure.

Comment: Also, for general hashtable development, I have found [Coding up a Hash Table](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/hashtables/section3.rhtml) and [Hash tables - eternally confuzzled](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx) useful.

Comment: I see, thanks pointing this out. `not_found[num_not_found]` is definitely `char` so I can change this to `malloc(LENGTH*sizeof(char))`? Sorry the code isn't MCVE, I tried to cut to avoid just dumping a bunch of code here.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll give them a read. The second one was broken but I think [this](http://itsharks.blogspot.com/2011/02/hash-eternally-confuzzled.html) is the correct one.

Comment: To copy `curToken` to `not_found[num_not_found]`, you should allocate `not_found[num_not_found] = malloc (strlen (curToken) + 1);` bytes. And don't forget to ***validate the return*** of each allocation before you copy to it, e.g. `if (!not_found[num_not_found]) { perror ("malloc-not_found[num_not_found]"); /* handle error as appropriate */ }` Which in your case may be to `return -1;` indicating failure within `check_file`, etc..

Comment: When I allocate `not_found[num_not_found]` using `malloc(strlen(curToken)+1)` I get >malloc.c:2401: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.

Comment: Then use `not_found[num_not_found] = malloc (strlen (pch) + 1);` There is no reason to use `curToken` and if `< LENGTH-1`, `curToken[LENGTH]=0;` terminates incorrectly. There is an error in your code somewhere, but it is not apparent from the sections you have posted. The purpose of a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is to provide something that can be compiled to duplicate your results so everyone here can identify exactly where the problem lies. With only snippets, there are portions where the error may originate that can only be guessed at.

Comment: Fair enough. I've posted a more discrete question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58109165/how-to-properly-malloc-item-in-struct-array-hashmap-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

I finally got rid of the buffer overflow problems mostly by following David's advice in the comments, plus figuring out that I had one more malloc than I needed. The fixes were:

1. `new_node->next` needed a malloc
2. The malloc for `new_node->next` should happen only if it's actually going to be used.
3. `not_found[num_not_found] = malloc(LENGTH*sizeof(not_found[num_not_found]));` was wrong and should have been `notfound[num_not_found] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(pch)+1))` (assuming pch wasn't null terminated). (Side note, for whatever reason, on my computer, `malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(pch)+1)` is not the same as `malloc(strlen(pch)+1)`)
4. The return of every malloc really does have to be validated.