# How to properly malloc item in struct array hashmap in C

Tags: c, arrays, hashmap, malloc, valgrind

In the following code, I'm using malloc for adding a new item to a hashmap. I thought I've checked all the boxes for properly using malloc, but valgrind says I've got a memory leak on them. Can someone point me to where I've gone wrong?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char content[46];
    struct node* next;
}
node;

typedef node* hashmap_t;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    hashmap_t hashtable[1000];

    node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(n == NULL) return 0;

    hashmap_t new_node = n;

    new_node->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(new_node->next == NULL) {
        free(n);
        return 0;
    }

    strncpy(new_node->content, "hello", 45);
    hashtable[10] = new_node;

    for(int y=0; y < 1000; y++) {
        if(hashtable[y] != NULL) {
            free(hashtable[y]->next);
            free(hashtable[y]);
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: We cannot possibly know what "some stuff" is. Without "some stuff" you are not assigning anything to any element of `hashtable`, so freeing them has undefined behaviour.

Comment: That's better. Where are the indexes in `hashtable` initialized? Right now `hashtable[y]` makes no sense as you have done nothing yet but declare `hashmap_t hashtable[1000];` (an array of 1000 `node`), but you never assign anything to `hashtable[X]`??  (`valgrind` or another *Memory Use/Error Check* program is your friend) Also, if `main` (or any function) takes no arguments in your program, `int main (void)` is the proper invokation to make that explicit. See: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1).

Comment: Your `hashtable` should be `hashmap_t *hashtable[1000] = {NULL};` to declare an ***array of pointers*** initialized to all `NULL`. Then you need to use a *hash_function* to create a hash of whatever value you are storing and in the hash function use `hash_result % 1000` to determine the index (*bucket*) and assign that node to `hashtable[hash_result % 1000]`. Then if you have a *collision* and 2 values would save to the same index -- that's where you use the linked-list to store the second value in the list at that index.

Comment: I've updated the code to put an item into the hashmap. In practice I'd be adding items from a file. I also updated the free condition to be `y < 1000` instead of `hashtable[y] != NULL`. With those changes, valgrind doesn't complain anymore about malloc, but instead tells me `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`, `Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()` and `Invalid read of size 8`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin makes sense, I will try adding that declaration.

Comment: Your `free` must be `for(int y=0; y < 1000; y++) { hashmap_t *p = hashtable[y]; while (p) { hashmap_t victim = p; p = p->next; free (victim); } }`. I have put together an example hashing dictionary words (`length < 64`). It contains 3 files, the header, the source, and a simple example reading words from a file (one-word per-line). [wordhash example](https://paste.opensuse.org/17755511). The best way to learn hashtables is through the links I provided earlier, and then work though an example. The code is reasonable commented.

Comment: The example will store as as many words as the file contains (it dynamically allocates) and it will maintain the `(load_factor < 0.6)` and automatically reallocate and rehash when the load factor is reached (e.g. number of buckets need to be increased). Just build it, and then `./wordhash_tst filename`. It will report the hashtable size (number of buckets), the number of buckets filled, and the load factor and then free all memory and return.

Comment: `typedef node* hashmap_t;` Do NOT `typedef` *pointers*... See: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers). Your `node` is a node in the linked-list to be used within your hashtable. You have NOT declared or initialized any hashtable yet. (**note:** the `hashmap` is a java class introduced in JDK 1.2). It looks like you are having terminology difficulties. In C, you will create an array of buckets. Filled buckets hold the starting `node` pointer (or your `hashmap_t`) Please clarify what you are after?

Comment: A million thank yous, @DavidC.Rankin for the beautiful code you posted and for the many clarifications. By following these tips I got valgrind to (mostly) stop complaining.

Comment: Glad to help. Digesting hastables is a fairly big learning step as you are combining a dynamically allocated set of pointers to use as your "buckets" with a linked-list starting from each bucket containing any terms that hash to the same bucket. And done correctly you are maintaining a ratio of filled/total buckets less than 0.6 for overall efficiency in table lookups. So you are sewing a number of tools together to produce a new tool with good insert efficiency and lightning fast retrieval. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the line

```
if(hashtable[y] != NULL)
```

You do not initialise `hashtable` to any value and it is also declared as a local variable. The initial value shall be some garbage value. So you cannot assume that if `hashtable[y]` shall be `NULL` for all 1000 elements of the array.

You can initialize the structure to zero while declaring e.g.

```
hashmap_t hashtable[1000] = {0};
```

or you can declare it as a global variable.